# Add multiLine QString in single row of QTableView

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview, qstring

QAbstractTableModel is used with QTableView

I want to show three lines text in single cell of QTableView

The cell may only occupy three lines,

Consider QStrings as:
QString A = "No failed tests found, a possible compilation error. Please Check";
QString B = "No failed tests found";

The QString A may only occupy two line. 
 This might be the first line or the second, depending of the length of the "QString A". 
When the QString A does not fit into two lines, 
it is cut at the end and an ellipsis (...) is shown instead of the cut text;
 
The cut position is after the last word that fits completely into the field (including the ellipsis).
 So the last word shown is complete
The QString B should occupy line three.

Eg:
these case may be as,

First Line = No failed tests found,a 
Second Line = possible compilation...
Third Line = No failed tests found

Comment: A cell you want to have a QString that shows if it is necessary in several lines or you want 2 QString in a cell, could indicate which is the structure of your model since the Qtableview depends highly on the model and this should provide the QStrings.

Comment: Hi, @eyllanesc i am using QAbstractTableModel and i want to have 2 strings in one cell(whose length may exceed beyond the width of the cell, for that i need ellipsis).

Comment: I could place 2 examples of strings to understand it better, I could also indicate how both strings are stored in their model to understand it correctly, even for me it is confusing.

Comment: Hi @eyllanesc, i have updated the question, please have a look if convenient. Thanks :)

Comment: Calling setWordWrap(true) on your QTableView will allow it to display multiple lines of text in a single cell (if the string-to-be-displayed contains carriage returns).  As for putting in the ellipses, I'm not sure if Qt has functionality for that, or if you'd have to dynamically reformat the text in response to column-width resizes.  My suggestion would be to try it without the ellipses (i.e. with just the normal column-clipping) first and see if you really need them -- in the past I've found it more helpful to not have them, since they often just take up space and get in the way of the text.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner unfortunately i cannot have carriage returns in the strings, I want to have carriage returns dyamically if the length of my string exceeds the columns width. as you said ,yes here I can ignore eliipsis.

Comment: Actually I think setWordWrap(true) will wrap strings without carriage returns also.

Comment: @jeremy It will be for one string , which may occupy all the three lines in the cell. I want to have first string to occupy maximum two lines and second string to occupy third line in the cell.